# Dynamically Set YTD IN T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to check if a start date passed into a query is this year and if so, set the end date to look at this year's YTD. Else if the start date is last year, set the end date to look at last year's YTD.

Comment: maybe some sample data and expected result would make clear what you are asking

Comment: And some explanation what YTD is, I'm too lazy to google

Comment: datepart(year, '20180101') = datepart(year, getdate())

Comment: passed in where? Where is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below script will give you YTD based on @StartDate.

```
DECLARE @StartDate date='01-Jan-2018'
DECLARE @YTD DATE 
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE=GETDATE()
select DATEDIFF(YEAR,@StartDate,@CurrentDate)
IF DATEDIFF(YEAR,@StartDate,@CurrentDate)>=1
BEGIN
    SET @YTD = '31-DEC-'+ CAST(YEAR(@StartDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
END 
ELSE IF DATEDIFF(YEAR,@StartDate,@CurrentDate)=0
BEGIN 
    SET @YTD = GETDATE()--OR you can set this to 31st Dec like above
END
```

Comment: this will fail very hard if your on an sql server that does not understand this date format. Always use regional free dateformats. See also http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Answer (score 0):

@DateStart is passed to the query.
You can create @DateEnd with CASE statement:

```
-- Declare variables
DECLARE
    @DateStart DATETIME = '2018-08-17' -- passed to the query
    , @DateEnd DATETIME;

-- Populate variable @DateEnd
SELECT @DateEnd =
    CASE
        WHEN YEAR(@DateStart) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(CONVERT(CHAR(4), @DateStart, 120), '-12-31'))
    END;

-- Show variable @DateEnd
SELECT @DateEnd;
```

To include "today", you can add 1 day and filter with less than (<):

```
-- Populate variable @DateEnd
SELECT @DateEnd =
    CASE
        WHEN YEAR(@DateStart) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        ELSE DATEADD(DD, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(CONVERT(CHAR(4), @DateStart, 120), '-12-31')))
    END;

-- Show variable @DateEnd
SELECT @DateEnd;

-- Use variable @DateEnd
SELECT
  ColumnName1
  , ColumnName2
  , ColumnName3
FROM TableName
WHERE DateTimeColumn < @DateEnd;
```